# How to set a pre-defined dynamic name for a variable in a jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: variables, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Is it possible to set a pre-defined dynamic name for a variable in a jenkins declarative pipeline ?

```
env {
  TEST_2_SERIAL = 456789
}
stage('Test') {
  steps {
    echo ${TEST_${HARDWARE}_SERIAL}
  }
}
```

when `${HARDWARE}` value is 2 and `${TEST_2_SERIAL}` value is predefined as 456789, then `${TEST_${HARDWARE}_SERIAL}` should be 456789

Comment: Nested string interpolation is generally not allowed in languages.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thank you. I was also of the opinion if it could work that way. Nevertheless, wanted to check in the community if anyone knew a way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it achieves what you expect but it is possible to access the environment variable dynamically in this way.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    environment {
        TEST_2_SERIAL = 456789
        HARDWARE = '2'
    }
    stages{
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo env["TEST_${HARDWARE}_SERIAL"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The echo will print out the value of `TEST_2_SERIAL`.